# Eclipse 'com.google.common.collect.ForwardingMultimap cannot be resolved. Referenced in class files' when using custom skull generator (Minecraft)

Tags: java, eclipse, guava, minecraft

I am using a SkullCreator class created by deanveloper ([GitHub Page](https://github.com/deanveloper/SkullCreator/blob/master/src/main/java/dev/dbassett/skullcreator/SkullCreator.java)). When I added it to my project, the error appears on the first line on the first character of the package keyword. (Yes I made sure to change the package correctly). I did research and found I needed to add Google Guava as a dependency. I added it and made sure it contained the ForwardingMultimap class, but the error still persists. Am I missing something with adding the dependency?

Dependency code:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>31.0.1-jre</version>
</dependency>
```

I am new to Maven and dependencies, so if I missed something that might be obvious please explain.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution. For anyone who wants to know, you must put the line 'requires com.google.common;' into your module-info.java file. An error will appear saying you must add this to the project dependencies. Once you do this, then it should work.